# Comma or no comma before a proper name in a "tag question"?

Tags: commas, questions, question-tags

**First question.** Which of these "tag question" variations is most correct?

1. You're going, right John?
2. You're going, right, John?
3. You're going. Right, John?

(1) looks best, imo. (2) seems more proper, though. (3) seems way too emphatic.

**Second question.** What is the technical/grammatical name for the person being addressed in these sentences? "John" is a proper name, obviously, but how do you describe its function within the sentences above? "Target"? "Object"? "Addressee"? I assume there's a more technical term for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your examples, *John* is a [noun of direct address](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/direct-address.html), which is always set off by commas. While this rule is still valid in formal registers, one often sees very short sentences without a comma:

> Welcome students. —  *instead of* —  Welcome, students.

That would suggest that

> You're going, right, John?

obeys the standard rule.

A semicolon might aid reading:

> You're going; right, John?

Comment: We likely have uestions about vocative commas.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!This actually raises a different "comma" question. Should I say, "Awesome! Thank you." or "Awesome! Thank you!" or "Awesome, thank you!"

Comment: All three are fine, though exclamation marks tend to be overused.

Comment: I see no reason to even consider a semicolon. Tag questions only need to be set off with a comma, to separate them from the main body of the sentence. It's not as if they're an independent clause.

Comment: A reader might parse _right_ as a direction. _Right_ is really _isn't that right_ or some such.

Comment: @KarlG. Some may do that, but it's not valid with a comma before "right". My reaction to the semicolon is **still**, WTF? / My solution, if writing informally, would probably be no comma before "John". / For formal writing, a period instead of the semicolon will work. / This sentence just seems too mundane for a semicolon. I prefer to reserve those for times when I want to wake up readers and grab their attention.